# FHSTwitterEngine image not post

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, fhs-twitter-engine

Post image with **FHStwitterEngine** it return error But if i post tweet without imahe than it post successfully

```
-(void)postTweet:(NSString*)message withImage:(UIImage*)img {

dispatch_async(GCDBackgroundThread, ^{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *strMsg =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",message];
        NSData *imgData =UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
        NSError *returnCode = [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]postTweet:strMsg withImageData:imgData];


        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

        NSString *title = nil;
        NSString *message = nil;


        if (returnCode) {
            title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error %d",returnCode.code];
            message = returnCode.localizedDescription;

        } else {
            title = @"Tweet Posted";
            message = message;
        }

        dispatch_sync(GCDMainThread, ^{
            @autoreleasepool {
                UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [av show];
            }
        });
    }
});

}

- (IBAction)btnPost:(id)sender {

    NSString *str =@"Test5";
    UIImage *image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"contact.png"];
    if (image ==nil) {
        [self postTweet:str];
    }else {

    [self postTweet:str withImage:image];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue with the current version of FHSTwitterEngine and posting images. I had the same issue in my app, but was able to solve it using the updates from this forked version:

https://github.com/alvani/FHSTwitterEngine/blob/master/FHSTwitterEngine/FHSTwitterEngine.m

It's easiest to just copy/paste that into FHSTwitterEngine.m, but here's the specific changes you'll need:

On or around Line 1599:

```
- (NSError *)sendPOSTRequestForURL:(NSURL *)url andParams:(NSDictionary *)params
...
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n",key] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];        
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:data];
```

Add the following code below:

```
if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSData class]]) {
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}
```

On or around Line 688:

```
- (NSError *)postTweet:(NSString *)tweetString withImageData:(NSData *)theData inReplyTo:(NSString *)irt {
...
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
params[@"media[]"] = theData;
```

Add the following code below:

```
params[@"status"] = tweetString;
```

Hope this helps!